# wget "awaiting response..." forever. Works fine for other sites or from another server

Tags: server, wget, file-transfer

I have spent hours and hours on this.  I have contacted my server provider who assures me they cannot block me.  I have contacted multiple people at NOAA and have been assured I am not blocked.  But about two weeks ago a script that has been working for 5 years quit working.  The script works from home but not from 1and1.  I see differences in what wget does but cannot see anything wrong.  The main difference is that one server translates the encoding to UTF-8 while the one that works does not.  I do not think that is the problem as I am not getting a file not found error and I see the same thing with sites that work fine. I am pasting the same exact text in both servers so no difference in my command.  I get no error message, just waiting for response.

This diagram is a summary of my tests.  It does not point to an obvious source of the problem so I am asking the experts here. Local and 1and1 are the servers, ndbc and noaa are the data sources.  As you can see, the data only fails with 1and1 but 1and1 only fails with one data source. By fail I mean connected but no response.

[image]

Here is what I see on my home server.
[image]
Everything is correct and the file is saved.

If I paste the exact same text into my 1and1 server I get this
[image]
No matter how long I wait, no response.

The interesting thing is that if I ask for an invalid file, I correctly get an ERROR 404 so I know they are responding to me.  ndbc says they can see my traffic and that they are not blocking me.
[image]

And finally, to show that wget works on other domains here is a fetch of the noaa home page:
[image]

Does anyone know what is going wrong either with something I am doing or with what ndbc.noaa might be doing or what might be wrong at 1and1 so I can get a handle on where the problem is?

I have implemented a kludge workaround by downloading the data to my myth server and using sftp to upload it to the 1and1 server but this is not a long term fix.

By the way, I see the same thing if I try using lynx to access www.ndbc.noaa.gov.  I can download their home page from my myth server but not from the 1and1 server.  I can use lynx to get home pages from www.noaa.gov from either server.

Comment: I just got off the phone with ndbc IT guy.  He says that they are sending 200 requests and the data.  He also saw my 404 tests.  But I don't get the 200 data.  He is going to contact his internet service (noaa) Monday and see if they are blocking it.  It is clearly a strange problem.

Comment: It looks like they fixed it.  I will post when I find out what was causing it.

Comment: OK, just got an email from ndbc.  They didn't do anything.  So after being out for weeks, it suddenly starts working without anyone doing anything.  How can this be?

Comment: Quit working again.  NDBC says they are sending me the data.  How can I determine if it is noaa or 1and1 that is the problem?